# Можно ли запретить срабатывания скрипта в некоторых местах сайта (хедер и меню)

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который увеличивает и уменьшает размер шрифта, нужно чтобы меню и хедер при этом оставались прежними. Можно ли реализовать? Если специальная функция в скрипте, которая может запретить работу в определенном месте?

Пример скрипта:

```js
button = document.createElement('input');
parentElem = document.body;
button.type = 'button';
button.id = 'minus';
button.className = 'no-scale';
button.value = ' А- ';
button.setAttribute("onclick", "fontSize(this)");
button.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed; z-index:9999; top:35px;left:35%; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;");
parentElem.insertBefore(button, parentElem.lastChild);

button = document.createElement('div');
parentElem = document.body;
button.innerHTML = 'Шрифт';
button.className = 'no-scale';
button.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed; z-index:9999; top:10px;left:37%; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;");
parentElem.insertBefore(button, parentElem.lastChild);


button = document.createElement('input');
parentElem = document.body;
button.type = 'button';
button.id = 'plus';
button.className = 'no-scale';
button.value = ' А+ ';
button.setAttribute("onclick", "fontSize(this)");
button.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed; z-index:9999; top:35px;left:59%; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;");
parentElem.insertBefore(button, parentElem.lastChild);

var fontS = 16,
  interval = 14;


function intervalSize(obj) {

  var allelem = document.querySelectorAll("*:not(.no-scale)");

  if (obj.id == "intervalPlus") {
    if (interval > 60) interval = 60;
    else interval += 10;
  } else {
    if (interval <= 15) interval = 15;
    else interval -= 10;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < allelem.length; i++) allelem[i].style.lineHeight = interval + "px";

}


function fontSize(obj) {

  var a = document.querySelectorAll("*:not(.no-scale)");

  if (obj.id == "plus") {
    if (fontS > 40) fontS = 40;
    else fontS += 10;
  } else {
    if (fontS <= 15) fontS = 15;
    else fontS -= 10;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i].style.fontSize = fontS + "px";

}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
```

Comment: У вас код не рабочий. Предоставьте рабочий пожалуйста

Comment: Добавила, реализован на скрипте

Comment: У вас в селекторе есть класс `.no-scale`. Добавьте его к хедеру в `html`.

Comment: <header сlass="no-scale"> таким образом? он не работает

Comment: Специальных функций таких нет. Вам надо правильно подобрать селектор. Не работает скорее всего из за того что вы используете нативный код и в вашем тестируемом браузере он не работает, то есть код не кроссбраузерный. Используйте решение на JS фреймворках типа jQuery.

Comment: а может потому что он ни где не фигурирует : var a = document.querySelectorAll("*:not(.no-scale)");    * - это отдельная папка с css, специально под скрипт, в этой же папке лежит и сам скрипт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно  обернуть контент в обертку и присвоить ей класс, например `js-scale`. И только контент внутри этого блока будет происходить изменение шрифта:

```js
button = document.createElement('input');
parentElem = document.body;
button.type = 'button';
button.id = 'minus';
button.className = 'no-scale';
button.value = ' А- ';
button.setAttribute("onclick", "fontSize(this)");
button.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed; z-index:9999; top:35px;left:35%; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;");
parentElem.insertBefore(button, parentElem.lastChild);

button = document.createElement('div');
parentElem = document.body;
button.innerHTML = 'Шрифт';
button.className = 'no-scale';
button.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed; z-index:9999; top:10px;left:37%; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;");
parentElem.insertBefore(button, parentElem.lastChild);


button = document.createElement('input');
parentElem = document.body;
button.type = 'button';
button.id = 'plus';
button.className = 'no-scale';
button.value = ' А+ ';
button.setAttribute("onclick", "fontSize(this)");
button.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed; z-index:9999; top:35px;left:59%; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;");
parentElem.insertBefore(button, parentElem.lastChild);

var fontS = 16,
  interval = 14;


function intervalSize(obj) {

  var allelem = document.querySelectorAll("*:not(.no-scale)");

  if (obj.id == "intervalPlus") {
    if (interval > 60) interval = 60;
    else interval += 10;
  } else {
    if (interval <= 15) interval = 15;
    else interval -= 10;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < allelem.length; i++) allelem[i].style.lineHeight = interval + "px";

}


function fontSize(obj) {

  var a = document.querySelectorAll(".js-scale");

  if (obj.id == "plus") {
    if (fontS > 40) fontS = 40;
    else fontS += 10;
  } else {
    if (fontS <= 15) fontS = 15;
    else fontS -= 10;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i].style.fontSize = fontS + "px";

}
```

```html
<header>Text</header>
<main class="js-scale">
  <div>Text</div>
  <div>Text</div>
</main>
<footer>Text</footer>
```